# Duplicates Query

Tags: sql

Can someone help me with this query please:

I have data where customers have multiple records (in a single table, this is a flat file read into a table) e.g.

```
Name  Policy
Fred  SSS
Fred  SST
Joe   SSS
```

I need to pull out all records where Policy='SSS' but where that customer only has a 'SSS' policy. So only Joe would be returned from above

Comment: It helps if you specify the variety of SQL you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name
from yourtable
group by name
having count(policy)=1 and max(policy)='SSS'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name
FROM tableName a
WHERE Policy = 'SSS'
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName b WHERE a.Name = b.Name)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f52b/2)